# Creating neo4j graph database from csv file using py2neo

Tags: python, csv, py2neo

I am currently working in a doctoral program and i am interested about Py2neo, so I am using it in order to perform some experiments using social graphs. However I got into newbie troubles. Excuse me for asking these simple questions.

I got a xml dataset containing data about publications of a jornal, I have converted it into a csv table, there are about 700 records and each record is composed by four fiels: date, title, keywords, author. So my first question is how to create a graph from this table programatically. I considered writing a python script which loops the csv table, reads for each row and columns fields and writes into nodes.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Code +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   #
   import csv
   from py2neo import neo4j, cypher
   from py2neo import node,  rel

   # calls database service of Neo4j
   #
   graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
   #
   # Create nodes and relationships from a csv table
   # since it's a csv table, a reader must be invoked


   ifile  = open('testeout5_cp.csv', "rb")
   reader = csv.reader(ifile)

   # clear database
   graph_db.clear()

   rownum = 0
   for row in reader:
        colnum = 0
        for col in row:
            titulo, autor, rel = graph_db.create(
            {"titulo": col[1]}, {"autor": col[3]}, (1, "eh_autor_de", 0)
            )
            print(titulo,  autor)  
   rownum += 1

   ifile.close()
```

================
I got this output (Fragment):
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 22 2013, 09:31:58)
[GCC 4.8.1 20130603 (Red Hat 4.8.1-1)] on aires2, Standard

> > > ```
> > >     (Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10392'), Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data /node/10393'))
> > >     (Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10394'), Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10395'))
> > >     (Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10396'), Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10397'))
> > >     (Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10398'), Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10399'))
> > >     (Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10400'), Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10401'))
> > >     (Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10402'), Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10403'))
> > >     (Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10404'), Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10405'))
> > > ```

=========
What is wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting in the output?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a py2neo expert, so can't help with that. However, have you tried using a different mechanism to create your graph? Since it is not very big, I would consider using a spreadsheet (I use that a *lot*) - it's dead easy.

See http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/03/importing-data-into-neo4j-spreadsheet.html for some more info.

Hope it makes sense.

Rik

Comment: Thank you, Rik for your suggestion. I will follow your suggestion. However, yesterday night,I did converted to Cypher using Nigel Small site [link](http://nigelsmall.com/xml2graph), so I will try both options.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong, your code looks good.

You print the nodes and get proper py2neo node instances. Try `print(titulo,  autor, rel)` to see if your relationship is also created.

Just check with the webinterface at `http://localhost:7474/webadmin/` if your data is there. Since you don't have too many nodes, you could try a simple cypher query to get all nodes and check if everything is ok.

```
START n=node(*) RETURN n;
```